# Why LinqPad can connect the Db while my console app. throws an SQL Exception for the same code?

Tags: c#, sql, windows, visual-studio-2010, linqpad

I run the code below

```
var connectionString="Data Source=MyFooServer.myDomaion.com;Initial Catalog=FooDb;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pizza";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    cmd.CommandText = q;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
}
```

from 2 different places:

1) LinqPad

2) A Console application in Visual Studio 2010

LinqPad works fine. No exceptions.
But the same code throws an **SQL exception**: *"The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context."*

**QUESTION:** Why I can connect to my database without any problem from LinqPad but not from the console application even tough I run the same code?

Comment: Check the Windows user that is executing your visual studio is the same that the one that started LINQPad.

Comment: here is a good link to read as well http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811889

Comment: @ken2k : They are the same users -I can see it in the Task Manager

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my machine helped... No idea what was the root cause of this behavior tough.

Comment: Did your password recently change without a full reboot? Changes to password don't propagate to apps/services until a full restart has been done. Just a thought.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use SQL username and password instead of Windows Inegrated Security.

```
var connctionString="Data Source=MyFooServer.myDomain.com;Initial Catalog=FooDb;Uid=Username; pwd=password"
```